# Date from XML saved as one day delay

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, couchbase

I am reading a date string from XML, sample below:

```
<fundingStart value="20/04/2013"/>
```

I can retrieve it correctly from the XML and I am converting it to DateTime before saving as JSON format in CouchBase.

However, my issue is that when the data is saved, it is one day delay. In the above date from XML, it is being save as 19/04/2013 instead.

My code:

```
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(source.FundingStartDate.Value))
    {
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(source.FundingStartDate.Value.ToString(), "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        destination.Funding.Start = startDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezones.

`20/04/2013` gets parsed to `2013-04-20 00:00` local time. CouchBase, like many other (document) databases, saves dates as UTC internally.

So depending on your timezone, converting that local time to UTC will yield `2013-04-19 23:00`, for GMT+1.

A quick fix would be to call `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` when reading the date, so:

```
 destination.Funding.Start = destination.Funding.Start.ToLocalTime();
```

I'm sure the CouchBase C# SDK has some option to let this happen for each datetime read from the database.

Comment: ToLocalTime() is not available when I am trying to use it.

Comment: So? What type is it? It's a `DateTime` member, so if `Start` is a nullable DateTime, use `Start.Value.ToLocalTime()`, after a null check.

Comment: Sorry, yes this is correct. Fixed it with: destination.Funding.Start = startDate.ToLocalTime();